# Boost Spirit Signals Successful Parsing Despite Token Being Incomplete

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-lex

I have a very simple path construct that I am trying to parse with boost spirit.lex.

We have the following grammar:

```
token := [a-z]+
path := (token : path) | (token)
```

So we're just talking about colon separated lower-case ASCII strings here.

I have three examples "xyz", "abc:xyz", "abc:xyz:".

The first two should be deemed valid. The third one, which has a trailing colon, should not be deemed valid. Unfortunately the parser I have recognizes all three as being valid. The grammar should not allow an empty token, but apparently spirit is doing just that. What am I missing to get the third one rejected?

Also, if you read the code below, in comments there is another version of the parser that demands that all paths end with semi-colons. I can get appropriate behavior when I activate those lines, (i.e. rejection of "abc:xyz:;"), but this is not really what I want.

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks.

```
#include <boost/config/warning_disable.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/lex_lexertl.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_operator.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace boost::spirit;
using boost::phoenix::val;

template<typename Lexer>
struct PathTokens : boost::spirit::lex::lexer<Lexer>
{
      PathTokens()
      {
         identifier = "[a-z]+";
         separator = ":";

         this->self.add
            (identifier)
            (separator)
            (';')
            ;
      }
      boost::spirit::lex::token_def<std::string> identifier, separator;
};


template <typename Iterator>
struct PathGrammar 
   : boost::spirit::qi::grammar<Iterator> 
{
      template <typename TokenDef>
      PathGrammar(TokenDef const& tok)
         : PathGrammar::base_type(path)
      {
         using boost::spirit::_val;
         path
            = 
            (token >> tok.separator >> path)[std::cerr << _1 << "\n"]
            |
            //(token >> ';')[std::cerr << _1 << "\n"]
            (token)[std::cerr << _1 << "\n"]
             ; 

          token 
             = (tok.identifier) [_val=_1]
          ;

      }
      boost::spirit::qi::rule<Iterator> path;
      boost::spirit::qi::rule<Iterator, std::string()> token;
};


int main()
{
   typedef std::string::iterator BaseIteratorType;
   typedef boost::spirit::lex::lexertl::token<BaseIteratorType, boost::mpl::vector<std::string> > TokenType;
   typedef boost::spirit::lex::lexertl::lexer<TokenType> LexerType;
   typedef PathTokens<LexerType>::iterator_type TokensIterator;
   typedef std::vector<std::string> Tests;

   Tests paths;
   paths.push_back("abc");
   paths.push_back("abc:xyz");
   paths.push_back("abc:xyz:");
   /*
     paths.clear();
     paths.push_back("abc;");
     paths.push_back("abc:xyz;");
     paths.push_back("abc:xyz:;");
   */
   for ( Tests::iterator iter = paths.begin(); iter != paths.end(); ++iter )
   {
      std::string str = *iter;
      std::cerr << "*****" << str << "*****\n";

      PathTokens<LexerType> tokens;
      PathGrammar<TokensIterator> grammar(tokens);

      BaseIteratorType first = str.begin();
      BaseIteratorType last = str.end();

      bool r = boost::spirit::lex::tokenize_and_parse(first, last, tokens, grammar);

      std::cerr << r << " " << (first==last) << "\n";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies in the meaning of `first` and `last` after your call to `tokenize_and_parse`. `first==last` checks if your string has been completely tokenized, you can't infer anything about grammar. If you isolate the parsing like this, you obtain the expected result:

```
  PathTokens<LexerType> tokens;
  PathGrammar<TokensIterator> grammar(tokens);

  BaseIteratorType first = str.begin();
  BaseIteratorType last = str.end();

  LexerType::iterator_type lexfirst = tokens.begin(first,last);
  LexerType::iterator_type lexlast = tokens.end();


  bool r = parse(lexfirst, lexlast, grammar);

  std::cerr << r << " " << (lexfirst==lexlast) << "\n";
```

Comment: I plugged in your code and the lexer's iterators are not equal. So at least the problem is detectable. However, is there any reason "r" should not be false. If I just give the parser ":" it return false, as it should.

Comment: In the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/parse_api/iterator_api.html) you can see that the parse functions "return true if none of the involved parser components failed, and false otherwise". The way I understand it is that if the grammar can match your "starting rule" (`path` in your example) it returns true independently of how much of the string has been parsed. This is the reason why you need to check `first==last` in order to make sure your whole text has been parsed.

Comment: That makes sense. Since writing the original post I've been experimenting with using operator ">" instead of operator ">>". When I do this I get an exception when that trailing colon is encountered. This seems a bit inconsistent with the behavior of the ">>" operator, but whatever the case I definitely have at least one path forward. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5):

I addition to to what llonesmiz already said, here's a trick using `qi::eoi` that I sometimes use:

```
path = (
           (token >> tok.separator >> path) [std::cerr << _1 << "\n"]
         | token                           [std::cerr << _1 << "\n"]
    ) >> eoi;
```

This makes the grammar **require** `eoi` (end-of-input) at the end of a successful match. This leads to the desired result:

http://liveworkspace.org/code/23a7adb11889bbb2825097d7c553f71d

```
*****abc*****
abc
1 1
*****abc:xyz*****
xyz
abc
1 1
*****abc:xyz:*****
xyz
abc
0 1
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what I finally ended up with. It uses the suggestions from both @sehe and @llonesmiz. Note the conversion to std::wstring and the use of actions in the grammar definition, which were not present in the original post.

```
#include <boost/config/warning_disable.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/lex_lexertl.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_operator.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

//
// This example uses boost spirit to parse a simple
// colon-delimited grammar.
//
// The grammar we want to recognize is:
//    identifier := [a-z]+
//    separator = :
//    path= (identifier separator path) | identifier
//
// From the boost spirit perspective this example shows
// a few things I found hard to come by when building my
// first parser.
//    1. How to flag an incomplete token at the end of input
//       as an error. (use of boost::spirit::eoi)
//    2. How to bind an action on an instance of an object
//       that is taken as input to the parser.
//    3. Use of std::wstring.
//    4. Use of the lexer iterator.
//

// This using directive will cause issues with boost::bind
// when referencing placeholders such as _1.
// using namespace boost::spirit;

//! A class that tokenizes our input.
template<typename Lexer>
struct Tokens : boost::spirit::lex::lexer<Lexer>
{
      Tokens()
      {
         identifier = L"[a-z]+";
         separator = L":";

         this->self.add
            (identifier)
            (separator)
            ;
      }
      boost::spirit::lex::token_def<std::wstring, wchar_t> identifier, separator;
};

//! This class provides a callback that echoes strings to stderr.
struct Echo
{
      void echo(boost::fusion::vector<std::wstring> const& t) const
      {
         using namespace boost::fusion;
         std::wcerr << at_c<0>(t) << "\n";
      }
};


//! The definition of our grammar, as described above.
template <typename Iterator>
struct Grammar : boost::spirit::qi::grammar<Iterator> 
{
      template <typename TokenDef>
      Grammar(TokenDef const& tok, Echo const& e)
         : Grammar::base_type(path)
      {
         using boost::spirit::_val;
         path
            = 
            ((token >> tok.separator >> path)[boost::bind(&Echo::echo, e,::_1)]
             |
             (token)[boost::bind(&Echo::echo, &e, ::_1)]
             ) >> boost::spirit::eoi; // Look for end of input.

          token 
             = (tok.identifier) [_val=boost::spirit::qi::_1]
          ;

      }
      boost::spirit::qi::rule<Iterator> path;
      boost::spirit::qi::rule<Iterator, std::wstring()> token;
};


int main()
{
   // A set of typedefs to make things a little clearer. This stuff is
   // well described in the boost spirit documentation/examples.
   typedef std::wstring::iterator BaseIteratorType;
   typedef boost::spirit::lex::lexertl::token<BaseIteratorType, boost::mpl::vector<std::wstring> > TokenType;
   typedef boost::spirit::lex::lexertl::lexer<TokenType> LexerType;
   typedef Tokens<LexerType>::iterator_type TokensIterator;
   typedef LexerType::iterator_type LexerIterator;

   // Define some paths to parse.
   typedef std::vector<std::wstring> Tests;
   Tests paths;
   paths.push_back(L"abc");
   paths.push_back(L"abc:xyz");
   paths.push_back(L"abc:xyz:");
   paths.push_back(L":");

   // Parse 'em.
   for ( Tests::iterator iter = paths.begin(); iter != paths.end(); ++iter )
   {
      std::wstring str = *iter;
      std::wcerr << L"*****" << str << L"*****\n";

      Echo e;
      Tokens<LexerType> tokens;
      Grammar<TokensIterator> grammar(tokens, e);

      BaseIteratorType first = str.begin();
      BaseIteratorType last = str.end();

      // Have the lexer consume our string.
      LexerIterator lexFirst = tokens.begin(first, last);
      LexerIterator lexLast = tokens.end();

      // Have the parser consume the output of the lexer.
      bool r = boost::spirit::qi::parse(lexFirst, lexLast, grammar);

      // Print the status and whether or note all output of the lexer 
      // was processed.
      std::wcerr << r << L" " << (lexFirst==lexLast) << L"\n";
   }
}
```