# Whitespace skipper when using Boost.Spirit Qi and Lex

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi, boost-spirit-lex

Let's consider following code:

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/lex_lexertl.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

namespace lex = boost::spirit::lex;
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

template<typename Lexer>
class expression_lexer
    : public lex::lexer<Lexer>
{
public:
    typedef lex::token_def<> operator_token_type;
    typedef lex::token_def<> value_token_type;
    typedef lex::token_def<> variable_token_type;
    typedef lex::token_def<lex::omit> parenthesis_token_type;
    typedef std::pair<parenthesis_token_type, parenthesis_token_type> parenthesis_token_pair_type;
    typedef lex::token_def<lex::omit> whitespace_token_type;

    expression_lexer()
        : operator_add('+'),
          operator_sub('-'),
          operator_mul("[x*]"),
          operator_div("[:/]"),
          value("\\d+(\\.\\d+)?"),
          variable("%(\\w+)"),
          parenthesis({
            std::make_pair(parenthesis_token_type('('), parenthesis_token_type(')')),
            std::make_pair(parenthesis_token_type('['), parenthesis_token_type(']'))
          }),
          whitespace("[ \\t]+")
    {
        this->self
            = operator_add
            | operator_sub
            | operator_mul
            | operator_div
            | value
            | variable
            ;

        std::for_each(parenthesis.cbegin(), parenthesis.cend(),
            [&](parenthesis_token_pair_type const& token_pair)
            {
                this->self += token_pair.first | token_pair.second;
            }
        );

        this->self("WS") = whitespace;
    }

    operator_token_type operator_add;
    operator_token_type operator_sub;
    operator_token_type operator_mul;
    operator_token_type operator_div;

    value_token_type value;
    variable_token_type variable;

    std::vector<parenthesis_token_pair_type> parenthesis;

    whitespace_token_type whitespace;
};

template<typename Iterator, typename Skipper>
class expression_grammar
    : public qi::grammar<Iterator, Skipper>
{
public:
    template<typename Tokens>
    explicit expression_grammar(Tokens const& tokens)
        : expression_grammar::base_type(start)
    {
        start                     %= expression >> qi::eoi;

        expression                %= sum_operand >> -(sum_operator >> expression);
        sum_operator              %= tokens.operator_add | tokens.operator_sub;
        sum_operand               %= fac_operand >> -(fac_operator >> sum_operand);
        fac_operator              %= tokens.operator_mul | tokens.operator_div;

        if(!tokens.parenthesis.empty())
            fac_operand           %= parenthesised | terminal;
        else
            fac_operand           %= terminal;

        terminal                  %= tokens.value | tokens.variable;

        if(!tokens.parenthesis.empty())
        {
            parenthesised         %= tokens.parenthesis.front().first >> expression >> tokens.parenthesis.front().second;
            std::for_each(tokens.parenthesis.cbegin() + 1, tokens.parenthesis.cend(),
                [&](typename Tokens::parenthesis_token_pair_type const& token_pair)
                {
                    parenthesised %= parenthesised.copy() | (token_pair.first >> expression >> token_pair.second);
                }
            );
        }
    }

private:
    qi::rule<Iterator, Skipper> start;
    qi::rule<Iterator, Skipper> expression;
    qi::rule<Iterator, Skipper> sum_operand;
    qi::rule<Iterator, Skipper> sum_operator;
    qi::rule<Iterator, Skipper> fac_operand;
    qi::rule<Iterator, Skipper> fac_operator;
    qi::rule<Iterator, Skipper> terminal;
    qi::rule<Iterator, Skipper> parenthesised;
};


int main()
{
    typedef lex::lexertl::token<std::string::const_iterator> token_type;
    typedef expression_lexer<lex::lexertl::lexer<token_type>> expression_lexer_type;
    typedef expression_lexer_type::iterator_type expression_lexer_iterator_type;
    typedef qi::in_state_skipper<expression_lexer_type::lexer_def> skipper_type;
    typedef expression_grammar<expression_lexer_iterator_type, skipper_type> expression_grammar_type;

    expression_lexer_type lexer;
    expression_grammar_type grammar(lexer);

    while(std::cin)
    {
        std::string line;
        std::getline(std::cin, line);

        std::string::const_iterator first = line.begin();
        std::string::const_iterator const last = line.end();

        bool const result = lex::tokenize_and_phrase_parse(first, last, lexer, grammar, qi::in_state("WS")[lexer.self]);
        if(!result)
            std::cout << "Parsing failed! Reminder: >" << std::string(first, last) << "<" << std::endl;
        else
        {
            if(first != last)
                std::cout << "Parsing succeeded! Reminder: >" << std::string(first, last) << "<" << std::endl;
            else
                std::cout << "Parsing succeeded!" << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

It is a simple parser for arithmetic expressions with values and variables. It is build using `expression_lexer` for extracting tokens, and then with `expression_grammar` to parse the tokens.

Use of lexer for such a small case might seem an overkill and probably is one. But that is the cost of simplified example. Also note that use of lexer allows to easily define tokens with regular expression while that allows to easily define them by external code (and user provided configuration in particular). With the example provided it would be no issue at all to read definition of tokens from an external config file and for example allow user to change variables from `%name` to `$name`.

The code seems to be working fine (checked on Visual Studio 2013 with Boost 1.61). Except that I have noticed that if I provide string like `5++5` it properly fails but reports as reminder just `5` rather than `+5` which means the offending `+` was "unrecoverably" consumed. Apparently a token that was produced but did not match grammar is in no way returned to the original input. But that is not what I'm asking about. Just a side note I realized when checking the code.

Now the problem is with whitespace skipping. I very much don't like how it is done. While I have done it this way as it seems to be the one provided by many examples including answers to questions here on StackOverflow.

The worst thing seems to be that (nowhere documented?) `qi::in_state_skipper`. Also it seems that I have to add the `whitespace` token like that (with a name) rather than like all the other ones as using `lexer.whitespace` instead of `"WS"` doesn't seem to work.

And finally having to "clutter" the grammar with the `Skipper` argument doesn't seem nice. Shouldn't I be free of it? After all I want to make the grammar based on tokens rather than direct input and I want the whitespace to be excluded from tokens stream - it is not needed there anymore!

What other options do I have to skip whitespaces? What are advantages of doing it like it is now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For some strange reason only now I found a different question, [Boost.Spirit SQL grammar/lexer failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18100628/boost-spirit-sql-grammar-lexer-failure), where [some other solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18106293/422489) to whitespace skipping is provided. A better one!

So below is the example code reworked along the suggestions there:

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/lex_lexertl.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

namespace lex = boost::spirit::lex;
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

template<typename Lexer>
class expression_lexer
    : public lex::lexer<Lexer>
{
public:
    typedef lex::token_def<> operator_token_type;
    typedef lex::token_def<> value_token_type;
    typedef lex::token_def<> variable_token_type;
    typedef lex::token_def<lex::omit> parenthesis_token_type;
    typedef std::pair<parenthesis_token_type, parenthesis_token_type> parenthesis_token_pair_type;
    typedef lex::token_def<lex::omit> whitespace_token_type;

    expression_lexer()
        : operator_add('+'),
          operator_sub('-'),
          operator_mul("[x*]"),
          operator_div("[:/]"),
          value("\\d+(\\.\\d+)?"),
          variable("%(\\w+)"),
          parenthesis({
            std::make_pair(parenthesis_token_type('('), parenthesis_token_type(')')),
            std::make_pair(parenthesis_token_type('['), parenthesis_token_type(']'))
          }),
          whitespace("[ \\t]+")
    {
        this->self
            += operator_add
            | operator_sub
            | operator_mul
            | operator_div
            | value
            | variable
            | whitespace [lex::_pass = lex::pass_flags::pass_ignore]
            ;

        std::for_each(parenthesis.cbegin(), parenthesis.cend(),
            [&](parenthesis_token_pair_type const& token_pair)
            {
                this->self += token_pair.first | token_pair.second;
            }
        );
    }

    operator_token_type operator_add;
    operator_token_type operator_sub;
    operator_token_type operator_mul;
    operator_token_type operator_div;

    value_token_type value;
    variable_token_type variable;

    std::vector<parenthesis_token_pair_type> parenthesis;

    whitespace_token_type whitespace;
};

template<typename Iterator>
class expression_grammar
    : public qi::grammar<Iterator>
{
public:
    template<typename Tokens>
    explicit expression_grammar(Tokens const& tokens)
        : expression_grammar::base_type(start)
    {
        start                     %= expression >> qi::eoi;

        expression                %= sum_operand >> -(sum_operator >> expression);
        sum_operator              %= tokens.operator_add | tokens.operator_sub;
        sum_operand               %= fac_operand >> -(fac_operator >> sum_operand);
        fac_operator              %= tokens.operator_mul | tokens.operator_div;

        if(!tokens.parenthesis.empty())
            fac_operand           %= parenthesised | terminal;
        else
            fac_operand           %= terminal;

        terminal                  %= tokens.value | tokens.variable;

        if(!tokens.parenthesis.empty())
        {
            parenthesised         %= tokens.parenthesis.front().first >> expression >> tokens.parenthesis.front().second;
            std::for_each(tokens.parenthesis.cbegin() + 1, tokens.parenthesis.cend(),
                [&](typename Tokens::parenthesis_token_pair_type const& token_pair)
                {
                    parenthesised %= parenthesised.copy() | (token_pair.first >> expression >> token_pair.second);
                }
            );
        }
    }

private:
    qi::rule<Iterator> start;
    qi::rule<Iterator> expression;
    qi::rule<Iterator> sum_operand;
    qi::rule<Iterator> sum_operator;
    qi::rule<Iterator> fac_operand;
    qi::rule<Iterator> fac_operator;
    qi::rule<Iterator> terminal;
    qi::rule<Iterator> parenthesised;
};


int main()
{
    typedef lex::lexertl::token<std::string::const_iterator> token_type;
    typedef expression_lexer<lex::lexertl::actor_lexer<token_type>> expression_lexer_type;
    typedef expression_lexer_type::iterator_type expression_lexer_iterator_type;
    typedef expression_grammar<expression_lexer_iterator_type> expression_grammar_type;

    expression_lexer_type lexer;
    expression_grammar_type grammar(lexer);

    while(std::cin)
    {
        std::string line;
        std::getline(std::cin, line);

        std::string::const_iterator first = line.begin();
        std::string::const_iterator const last = line.end();

        bool const result = lex::tokenize_and_parse(first, last, lexer, grammar);
        if(!result)
            std::cout << "Parsing failed! Reminder: >" << std::string(first, last) << "<" << std::endl;
        else
        {
            if(first != last)
                std::cout << "Parsing succeeded! Reminder: >" << std::string(first, last) << "<" << std::endl;
            else
                std::cout << "Parsing succeeded!" << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

The differences are following:

1. `whitespace` token is added to lexer's `self` as all other tokens.
2. However, an action is associated with it. The action makes the lexer ignore the token. Which is exactly what we want.
3. My `expression_grammar` no longer takes `Skipper` template argument. And so it is also removed from rules.
4. `lex::lexertl::actor_lexer` is used instead of `lex::lexertl::lexer` since now there is an action associated with a token.
5. I'm calling `tokenize_and_parse` instead of `tokenize_and_phrase_parse` as I don't need to pass skipper anymore.
6. Also I changed first assignment to `this->self` in lexer from `=` to `+=` as it seems more flexible (resistant to order changes). But it doesn't affect the solution here.

I'm good with this. It suites my needs (or better to say my taste) perfectly. However I wonder whether there are any other consequences of such change? Is any approach preferred in some situations? That I don't know.

Comment: Same answer is given in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13361519/troubles-with-boostspiritlex-whitespace within the "Simplify and profit". How did I miss those?!

Comment: Thanks for self answering w/credit. I didn't have the time (and frankly, I don't like Lex that much...)

Comment: @sehe If only Qi supported regex-based matching... Or does it?

Comment: Nice! You can add to your answer that having a separate state inside the lexer for skipping white spaces has another considerable drawback: lack of debugging support. If you use a separate state for skipping and then use BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE, you won't get the full output of the token stream. This is because the default debug handler advances the lexer iterator to get tokens, the lexer is of course in the INITIAL state. As soon as it meets a white space, the iteration stops, because the lexer cannot find a match. The token stream will be cut at the first white space in the rule's trace.

Comment: I found where this approach doesn't work. If you have several expressions for white space, you can list them all together in the in-state rule: “this->self("WS") = token_def<>("[ \\t\\n]+") | "\\/\\*[^*]*\\*+([^/*][^*]*\\*+)*\\/" | "\\/\\/[^\n]*"”. In the code you listed in your answer you would have to define several tokens.

Comment: @noxmetus Since this is a regex couldn't you just join all the definitions with `|` regex operator (and add proper parenthesis)? But also making a `vector` of whitespace tokens doesn't seem a big problem to me.

Comment: I can. Though I would prefer to create several token definitions. Like `whitespace`, `ccomment`, `cppcomment` and skip them all with `lex::_pass = lex::pass_flags::pass_ignore`. It will be much clearer than a long regex. I now think it's actually a benefit comparing to the instate skipper.